# Draw Route between two points using Google Directions in Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to Draw Route between two points using Google Directions in Google Map Android API using   [Draw Route between two points using Google Directions](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/google-maps-draw-path-two-points-using-google-directions-google-map-android-api-v2/)

everything is fine when I run the code I find the Map and I can make two markers. The problem here is in no route and when I look at Android Studio Logcat i find this error:

> "error_message" : "Keyless access to Google Maps Platform is
>   deprecated. Please use an API key with all your API calls to avoid
>   service interruption

I looked it up and I found that Since June 11th 2018, Google began enforcing the use of API keys so I changed my URL from

> String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

to

> String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters + "&key=" + MY_API_KEY

MY_API_KEY as per my project Credentials.

But the error is still appears. I also find that the billing associated with your projects needs to be in google map although the key is free. You can use it with any of your applications that call the Maps SDK for Android but it still asking for billing so I must have an online credit card and it's not available for me right now.

So any suggestion about how to solve this problem?

Is there any other API can I use than Google Maps API?

Comment: Can you doublecheck if maps and roads API is enabled for your project, and that access restrictions (if any) you put on your key still let you to use it the way you do?

Comment: @AnhaytAnanun I checked the Maps SDK for android and it's enabled so are there any other API can I check? Could you explain the second statement ?  for my Application restrictions I choose Android apps

Comment: Please, check if Directions API is also enabled. If it is enabled, too, remove the constraint from your key (not the best practice, but this may help).

Comment: Also, please, use this documentation as reference to build your query url - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start?hl=en_US. You can also reuse one of following libraries: https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android or https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

Comment: I checked Directions API, it is enabled. Constraint like What?. Thank you so much For libraries and for help . I will try to use one of them. Have a good day :)